# JSON object not found if embedding Rhino via the Java Scripting API

Tags: java, json, rhino

I can embed Rhino1_7R4 in my Java 6.x application like this, using the standard Java Scripting API:

```
ScriptEngine jsEngine = (new ScriptEngineManager()).getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.put("object1", object1);
jsEngine.eval(jsScript);
```

Which is nice and elegant. However I cannot call `JSON.stringify` from my js code, because it complains about the missing `JSON` object.

After dusting off some old docs there is an alternative way to this, using `org.mozilla.javascript.*` classes:

```
Context jsContext = Context.enter();
Scriptable jsScope= jsContext.initStandardObjects();
jsContext.evaluateString(jsScope, jsScript, "myscript.js", 1, null);
```

...and suddenly the `JSON` object is there! There are some other things missing though, like the importPackage() function, so instead of this:

```
importPackage(fj.data);
```

I have to use an alias:

```
fj = Packages.fj.data;
```

It seems to me that both approaches have their drawbacks. What is the "official" way of embedding Rhino and accessing all the functionality within it?

Comment: Rhino 1.7 [implements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/New_in_Rhino_1.7R4) JavaScript [1.7 as defined by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference). JSON wasn't added until JavaScript 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same code

```
Context jsContext = Context.enter();
Scriptable jsScope= jsContext.initStandardObjects();
jsContext.evaluateString(jsScope, jsScript, "myscript.js", 1, null);
```

Rhino complains that JSON is not defined.